# Does Google Firebase charge for inactive user accounts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, price

Consider an app which allows users to cancel their subscription but which keeps the user data stored on Google Firebase. That is, the user is not actually deleted from Firebase, but he's just flagged as inactive. If the user later on decides to activate his subscription again, this app just removes the inactive flag from the user, and restores everything the user had access to until he had cancelled his subscription.

This means of course Firebase would have to maintain the user's data forever, even though some users may never came back again. Or at least the data would have to be kept for say one year or so, which would be a grace period in which the user would have the chance to come back and still have his data available in the app.

My question is: would Google charge for this inactive user data during the time the user is inactive? Or does it charge only for active users?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. Contact Firebase Customer Service for information related to cost information and policies.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase is 18+ products, so it really helps if you are explicit about which specific data in which specific product you're asking about.

On Firebase Authentication there is no charge for inactive users, nor a charge for active users. The only charge is for signing in with a phone number (above the free quota), but that won't apply to inactive users.

Cloud Firestore has no concept of active or inactive users. It does however **charge for the data that you store in it**, and for read/write/delete operations you perform on it, and for the bandwidth that is consumed while reading data. If you store user data in Firestore, you will always pay for the storage of that data, even during periods when the data is not accessed.

For more on this, see the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page, which is quite complete on what products are charged and how.